# How to sum spectra in xmgrace?

Tags: batch-file, xmgrace

I have a batch file for xmgrace. When I plot several sets of voltage signal measurements, the batch file Fourier-transforms them all and moves them to a different graph. I would like to add a command to the batch file, that will sum the Fourier-transformed plots of frequency. By that I mean that I want xmgrace to sum together the y values of all the data sets for each x value. All the data sets are the same length. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, it was very easy. Added `s0.y = s0.y + s1.y + s2.y + s3.y` to my batch file. This sums all the y-values into one of the sets. I then added `kill s1`, `kill s2`, etc. to get rid of the others.